# find increment dependence between numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, linear-programming, puzzle

I have this sequenton (total 50 numbers)

```
5,7,8,10,12,13,15,17,18,20,22,24,26,28,29,31,33,35,38,40,42,44,47,49,51,54,56,59,62,65,68,71,74,77,81,84,88,91,95,99,104,108,113,118,123,128,133,139,145,151
```

Does anyone have an idea how find increment dependence between those numbers ?

Comment: Just in case, index 1 = 5, index 2 = 7 ...... index 50 = 151

Comment: There must be some decimal values, but the numbers are rounded.